# JUnit throwing IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, junit

I'm trying to Parameterize a JUnit4 test, but I keep receiving IllegalArgumentExcpetion: Wrong number of arguments, though I've triple checked my constructors. My code is like (please notice that variables are defined in top of classes as same type):

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class OrderTest {

private Order order;

public OrderTest(byte id, byte coffee, byte cafelatte, byte smoothie, byte iceCoffee) {
    order = new Order(new byte[] {id, coffee, cafelatte, smoothie, iceCoffee});
}

@Parameters
public static Collection order() {
    return Arrays.asList(new byte[][] {
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {2, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {3, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {14, 80, 127, 127, 127}
    });
}
```

And my `Order` class is

```
public class Order {

public Order(byte[] orders) {
    id = orders[0];
    coffee = orders[1];
    cafeLatte = orders[2];
    smoothie = orders[3];
    iceCoffee = orders[4];
}
```

Comment: And what *exactly* is the exception? Ideally, provide a [mcve] rather than just snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a workaround with boxed `Byte`-s:

```
public OrderTest(Byte id, Byte coffee, Byte cafelatte, Byte smoothie, Byte iceCoffee) {
    order = new Order(new byte[] {id, coffee, cafelatte, smoothie, iceCoffee});
}

@Parameters
public static Collection order() {
    return Arrays.asList(new Byte[][] {
        {1, 1, 0, 0, 0},
        {2, 1, 1, 0, 0},
        {3, 1, 1, 1, 1},
        {14, 80, 127, 127, 127}
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's make it simple and clean:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class OrderTest {

    @Parameterized.Parameter
    public Order order;

    @Parameterized.Parameters
    public static Collection<Order> orders() {
        return Arrays.asList(
            new Order(1, 1, 0, 0, 0),
            new Order(2, 1, 1, 0, 0),
            new Order(3, 1, 1, 1, 1),
            new Order(14, 80, 127, 127, 127)
        );
    }
```

If you implement a `toString()` method to `Order`, you can replace `@Parameterized.Parameters` with `@Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: {0}")` in order to have a better idea of what is currently tested.